# Circle Border for Menu

Tags: html, css

Im Designing A Sidebar Menu : [Here is My Design](http://oi61.tinypic.com/1tkkqv.jpg)
I need To Make it Like This : [Here is simple](http://oi60.tinypic.com/34p1h5t.jpg)

[image] [image]

Here is My Used Code:

**css**

```
.categories li.active a {
    color: #AC1735;
    border-left: 3px solid #AC1735;
    font-weight:bolder
}
.categories li a {
    padding-left:20px !important;
    padding-right:20px !important;
}
/*CATEGORIES*/
.categories {
    padding:0 !important;
}
.categories li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    padding:0 !important;
}
.categories li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
.categories li a {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    color:#AC1735;
    position:relative;
    padding:15px 50px 15px 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.categories li a:hover {
    color: #D52347;
    border-left: 3px solid #AC1735;
    font-weight:bolder
}
.categories li.active a {
    color: #AC1735;
    border-left: 3px solid #AC1735;
    font-weight:bolder
}
.categories.right a {
    padding-right:20px;
}
.categories.right a:before {
    left:20px;
    right:auto;
    background-position:-161px 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul class="categories right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">All recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tips and Tricks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: We're not a code writing service...what have you tried to make your existing menu like your required example?

Comment: Use a background image on the active `li`

Comment: use background image

Comment: @Paulie_D I designed A First One .. I need To Make it like Second one

Comment: Which is what I said...what have **you** done to make your first one into the second one?

Comment: @AlexThomas Can You do it .. I tried But always Fail :( .

Comment: @Mirr0rs "@AlexThomas Can You do it .. I tried But always Fail :(" Errr, no. Try it yourself first, show us what you've tried and then we can help.

Comment: @Paulie_D i need to make The First One Like The Second one :( .. I Made Border From left But I Need To make it Circle

Comment: **What part of "What have you done?" don't you understand?** ...Stack Overflow is not here to write your code for you.

Comment: @Paulie_D I Done Da First one ... This One : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg5xE.png And Attached Code For it ..

Comment: "You Done Da First One..." so now "Do Da Other." **I give up!**

Comment: @Paulie_D i just need to change Small Code For CSS To Make It Round

Comment: yes @Paulie_D, you should give up. Its a perfectly legitimate question, with interesting explanations i.e. why he cannot play with border-radius alone here (the height of the li, hence there has to be something else `:before`). You are so hell bent on denying him a proper solution, that you yourself forgot the basics of Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try pseudo element `:after` or `:before` [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kFizL)

```
.categories li a:hover{color: #D52347;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid #AC1735; font-weight:bolder}
.categories li a:hover:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #AC1735;
}
```

Comment: remove `float:left` from `a` and 'li'

Comment: Thanks YOur Code Did it ,,

Comment: Thanks Alot for your help After your edits it's working Awesome .. Thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

**[live demo](http://jsbin.com/hogak/3/edit)**

[image]

```
ul.categories{
  border-left: 2px solid #8592BD;
  list-style:none;
  padding:10px;
}
ul.categories a{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding: 5px;
  color:#000;
}
ul.categories li.active a:before,
ul.categories li:hover  a:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:8px;
  left:-16px;
  content: " ";
  width:10px; height:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: #38c;
}
```

Comment: It's Awesome i used it ... THanks <3

Comment: @EmmadZahid sorry I did not know you don't know how to use the `:hover` pseudo. Edited my answer.